# How to add multiple HTML code using $("body").append() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a bookmarklet using jQuery, but I am getting a syntax error while appending multiple HTML commands in the body using $("body").append(" "); Is  there any other way to append multiple HTML commands using jQuery?

Actually, I was making this Bookmarklet in reference to a tutorial: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/make-your-own-bookmarklets-with-jquery/

I am even sending the code for the bookmarklet:

## bookmarklet.js

```
(function () {

    var v = "1.3.2";

    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery < v) {
        var done = false;
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + v + "/jquery.min.js";
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
                done = true;
                initMyBookmarklet();
            }
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    } else {
        initMyBookmarklet();
    }

    function initMyBookmarklet() {
        (window.myBookmarklet = function () {
            function getSelText() {
                var s = '';
                if (window.getSelection) {
                    s = window.getSelection();
                } else if (document.getSelection) {
                    s = document.getSelection();
                } else if (document.selection) {
                    s = document.selection.createRange().text;
                }
                return s;
            }
            if ($("#wikiframe").length == 0) {
                var s = "";
                s = getSelText();
                if (s == "") {
                    var s = prompt("Forget something?");
                }
                if ((s != "") && (s != null)) {
                    $("body").append("<div id='wikiframe'>
                                      <div id='wikiframe_veil' style=''>
                                      <p>Loading...</p>
                                      </div>
                                      <iframe src='http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?&search=" + s + "' onload=" $('#wikiframe iframe').slideDown(500); ">Enable iFrames.</iframe>
                                    <style type='text/css'>
                                                    #wikiframe_veil { display: none; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25); cursor: pointer; z-index: 900; }
                                                    #wikiframe_veil p { color: black; font: normal normal bold 20px/20px Helvetica, sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 10em; margin: -10px auto 0 -5em; text-align: center; }
                                                    #wikiframe iframe { display: none; position: fixed; top: 10%; left: 10%; width: 80%; height: 80%; z-index: 999; border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5); margin: -5px 0 0 -5px; }
                                    </style>
                                    </div> "); //the append tag ends here, but the browser is showing syntax error on appending multiple HTML codes
                    $("#wikiframe_veil").fadeIn(750);
                }
            } else {
                $("#wikiframe_veil").fadeOut(750);
                $("#wikiframe iframe").slideUp(500);
                setTimeout("$('#wikiframe').remove()", 750);
            }
            $("#wikiframe_veil").click(function (event) {
                $("#wikiframe_veil").fadeOut(750);
                $("#wikiframe iframe").slideUp(500);
                setTimeout("$('#wikiframe').remove()", 750);
            });
        })();
    }

})();
```

So is there any way to get rid of this error. I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @htoniv Thanks for editing and making my post better. Thank you for the help as I am pretty new to Stack Exchange. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately JavaScript breaks the parsing when you have a text string on multiple lines like that, you have to open and close the quotes on the same line. However there are few ways to cope with this:

You should collapse the `.append()` argument on a single line and return a single continuous HTML string like this:

```
$("body").append("<div id='wikiframe'><div id='wikiframe_veil' style=''><p>Loading...</p></div></div>");
```

or if you want to keep code indented for better legibility then you can concatenate the multiple lines appending a plus at the end of each line like this:

```
$("body").append("<div id='wikiframe'>" + 
                     "<div id='wikiframe_veil' style=''>" +
                          "<p>Loading...</p>" +
                     "</div>" +
                 "</div>");
```

My suggestion (and probably ideal way as it looks cleaner) would be to load an array with your lines of HTML, then join the array again with an empty space in this fashioned way:

```
var html = [
  '<div id="wikiframe">',
     '<div id="wikiframe_veil" style="">',
        '<p>Loading...</p>',
     '</div>',
  '</div>',
];

$("body").append(html.join(''));
```

Now, your code is clean, readable and the HTML injected on the page would single line and already compressed

https://jsfiddle.net/e2bt47c0/

---

### 2021 ES6+ version

Update to the answer, if your project has a transpiler active for ES6 and you can use template strings you can do the following which is much easier and cleaner:

```js
$("body").append(`
  <div id="wikiframe">
      <div id="wikiframe_veil" style="">
        <p>Loading...</p>
      </div>
  </div>
`);
```

Comment: Thanks @MacK. Well the concept of making an array and joining it actually worked. Thank You for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could put the HTML in a single line (no cr break) or escape them with '\' eg:

```
"<div id='wikiframe'><div id='wikiframe_veil' style=''><p>Loading...</p></div>"
```

or,

```
"<div id='wikiframe'>\
    <div id='wikiframe_veil' style=''>\
    <p>Loading...</p>\
    </div>\
</div>"
```

Another approach, using the Grave accent symbol ( ` ):

```
`<div id='wikiframe'>
    <div id='wikiframe_veil' style=''>
    <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: I have tried adding \ after each line but still getting error!

Comment: I tried replacing the " (double quote) with ` (grave accent) and removed that '\', seems to work fine with multiple lines too. Try it maybe?

Comment: Works fine on my local machine. Again tried on jsfiddle, but perhaps the <style> block is bugging there... Here's what it's like with style tags are removed. https://jsfiddle.net/oer7bf4w/1/

Comment: The grave accent is a ES6 templating method, it might work for latest browsers but it might be broken on few versions back, I wouldn't recommend to use it until every browser is 100% ES6 compliant